# runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h) : LeetoCode 907

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am trying 907. Sum of Subarray Minimums on Leetcode.

I keep getting this error:

```
Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9
```

Here is what I tried (I understand it is very naive and will most probably TLE, but I would also like to know what is wrong such that it doesnt work) :-

```
class Solution {
public:
    int sumSubarrayMins(vector<int>& arr) {
        vector<int> ans;
        int sum =0; 
        int mn=0;
        int m = 1000000007;
        int n = arr.size();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<n; i++){
            for(int j = i; j<n; j++){
                for(int k = i; k<j; k++){
                    ans.push_back(arr[k]);
                }
                sort(ans.begin(), ans.end());
                mn = ans[0];
                sum = sum + mn;
                ans.clear();
            }
        }
        return sum%m;
    }
};
```

What is happening?

Comment: When a question asks for an answer "modulo some number", it is always a sign that you will overflow unless you maintain the "modulo some number" all the way. (`(a + b) % m == ((a % m) + (b % m)) % m` is an important equality.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first iteration,

- `ans` has no elements
- `i = 0`
- `j = i` (`j = 0`)

Then no elements will be pushed to `ans` because `i < j` is false.

Therefore, `mn = ans[0];` is invalid out-of-range access because `ans` still has no elements.